# Terraform loop path to create policies for each "sub path"

Tags: terraform

We have a use case, where we get a path like `team/project/store` and need to generate for each "sub path" (like for `team`, `team/project` and `team/project/store`) an entry inside a template. 
Unfortunately, we are unable to find a [Terraform functions](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions) to achieve this. Does anyone have a hint, how a path like `team/project/store` could be "separated" in the parts as shown above, so we could render for each "sub path" the needed policy?

Getting the path `team/project/store` should render the following content:

```
path "team" {
  capabilities = ["list"]
}

path "team/project" {
  capabilities = ["list"]
}

path "team/project/store" {
  capabilities = ["list"]
}
```

Comment: @MarkoE We have been unable to see a way to achieve this with a Terraform function. But might someone have another approach / idea?

Comment: Ah, and `split` cannot do the job you want?

Comment: @MarkoE `split` will only return the parts between the `/ `. So I'm unable to reconstruct the path?

Comment: It will create a list of elements. So if you give it `team/project/store` it will return `["team", "project", "store"]`. Then you could do string concatenation, e.g., `parts = split("team/project/store")`. Then `first = parts[0]`, `second = parts[0] + parts[1]§ etc.

Comment: let's say, I will process `store`. How could I rebuild the actual path of `team/project/store` when I only have the value `store` and the index of it?

Comment: I don't know. Then you don't have to split anything, right? :) You know the other part of the path so you can do string concatenation once again. Why would you go backwards to create a path?

Comment: Are you attempting to manage your Vault policies with Terraform? This is not really a good use case for TF. You should consider another tool.

Comment: @MattSchuchard why not, and what would you suggest as an alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following snipped would render the policy as needed with the use of [Built-in Functions](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions) and [String Templates](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/strings#string-templates).

```
locals {
  path       = "team/project/store"
  path_parts = split("/", local.path)
  paths = [
    for i, v in local.path_parts : join("/", slice(local.path_parts, 0, i + 1))
  ]
}

output "policy" {
  value = <<EOT
%{for path in local.paths}
path "${path}" {
  capabilities = ["list"]
}
%{endfor}
EOT
}

# Changes to Outputs:
#     + policy = <<-EOT

#         path "team" {
#             capabilities = ["list"]
#         }

#         path "team/project" {
#             capabilities = ["list"]
#         }

#         path "team/project/store" {
#             capabilities = ["list"]
#         }

#     EOT
```